# Check adjacent indices in a multidimensional array having into account the borders

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I did this so I can know how many asterisks appear in the adjacent squares.

```
private int CheckAdjacents(Coordinate cord)
{
    List<Coordinate> coordinates = new List<Coordinate>()
    {
        new Coordinate(cord.X - 1, cord.Y - 1), 
        new Coordinate(cord.X, cord.Y-1),
        new Coordinate(cord.X + 1, cord.Y -1),  
        new Coordinate(cord.X + 1, cord.Y),
        new Coordinate(cord.X + 1, cord.Y + 1), 
        new Coordinate(cord.X, cord.Y + 1),
        new Coordinate(cord.X - 1, cord.Y + 1), 
        new Coordinate(cord.X - 1, cord.Y)
    };

    return coordinates.Count(x => _matrix.At(x).Value == '*');
}
```

The thing here is that obviously it returns an exception because is checking indexes that wouldn't be checked. What'd be the best way to skip those kind of indexes? Using a try/catch could be kinda tricky? Thanks!

---

### EDIT:

### Matrix class

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MineSweeper
{
    public record Coordinate (int X, int Y);
    public record Size(int M, int N);

    public class Matrix
    {
        private readonly Size _size;
        private readonly Cell[,] _matrix;
        private const char InitValue = '.';

        public Matrix(Size size)
        {
            _size = size;
            _matrix = new Cell[size.M, size.N];
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        { 
            for (int m = 0; m < _size.M; m++)
                for (int n = 0; n < _size.N; n++)
                    _matrix[m, n] = new Cell(InitValue);
        }

        public Size GetSize()
            => _size;

        public Cell At(Coordinate coordinate) 
            => _matrix[coordinate.X, coordinate.Y];
        
        public void SetMine(Coordinate coordinate) 
            => _matrix[coordinate.X, coordinate.Y] = new Cell('*');

        public void ChangeValue(Coordinate coordinate, char value)
            => _matrix[coordinate.X, coordinate.Y] = new Cell(value);
        
        public Cell Open(Coordinate coordinate)
            => _matrix[coordinate.X, coordinate.Y];

        public IEnumerable ToList()
            => _matrix.Cast<Cell>().ToList();

        private string CellsAsString()
            => string.Concat(_matrix.OfType<Cell>().Select(c => c.Value));
        
        public override bool Equals(object other)
            => this.CellsAsString().Equals((other as Matrix)?.CellsAsString());
        
        public override int GetHashCode()
            => this.CellsAsString().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT(2):

### PrintMatrix and Open methods from the main class.

```
public void Open(Coordinate coordinate)
{
    if (_matrix.At(coordinate).Value == '*')
        HasLose = true;

    int numOfMines = _matrix.NeighborsOf(coordinate).Count(cell => cell.Value == '*');
    _showedMatrix.ChangeValue(coordinate, char.Parse(numOfMines.ToString()));

    HasWin = PlayerHasWin();
}


public String PrintMatrix()
{
    string temp = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < _size.M; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < _size.N; y++)
        {
            temp += _showedMatrix.At(new Coordinate(x, y)).Value;
        }
        temp += '\n';
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Notice that I'm using a `showedMatrix` which is another matrix with cells and its value for each one is a simple `.`. I'm using this new matrix so I can change its value and printing it.

These are the two tests that fail.

```
[Fact]
public void CellIsOpenWithoutAMineButWithOneMineAdjacent()
{
    string printExpected = "1...\n....\n....\n....\n";

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix(new(4, 4));
    matrix.SetMine(new(0,1));
    
    MineSweeper mineSweeper = new(matrix, 2);
    mineSweeper.Open(new(0,0));
    
    mineSweeper.PrintMatrix().Should().Be(printExpected);
}

[Fact]
public void CellIsOpenWithoutAMineButWithTwoMineAdjacent()
{
    string printExpected = "2...\n....\n....\n....\n";

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix(new(4, 4));
    matrix.SetMine(new(0,1));
    matrix.SetMine(new(1,0));
    
    MineSweeper mineSweeper = new(matrix, 2);
    mineSweeper.Open(new(0,0));
    
    mineSweeper.PrintMatrix().Should().Be(printExpected);
}
```

Since I'm aware that my main class for these tests is putting 2 random mines plus the mines I'm putting by myself with the `SetMine()` method, I executed these tests several times to make sure that it was failing. The conclusion was that `"2...\n....\n....\n....\n";` for some reason is always a 0 instead of a 2, or a 1.

Comment: "Check" is a very general term. What exactly is it that you want to do with the adjacent elements? Also, what is `_matrix` and where is it coming from?

Comment: matrix is a class which have a multidimensional array of cells, basically with the method At I can access to the Cell at some coordinate and its property Value, I need to know the value of the adjacent elements so I can count how many of them has an asterisk as value, I'll edit the question with the Matrix class anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest an iterator method on the matrix itself, that took care of checking the bounds before returning the cells, something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Cell> NeighborsOf(Coordinate coord)
{
  // if coord is not in bounds of the matrix, throw an argument exception

  for (int x = Math.Max(coord.X - 1, 0); x <= Math.Min(coord.X + 1, _size.M - 1); x++)
  {
    for (int y = Math.Max(coord.Y - 1, 0); y <= Math.Min(coord.Y + 1, _size.N - 1); y++)
    {
      if ((x,y) == (coord.X, coord.Y)) continue;

      yield return At(new Coordinate(x, y));
    }
  }
}
```

The `for` loops define the "3x3 window" of coordinates (central cell +/- 1) describing a maximum block of 9 cells, that has its edges limited by the `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` calls. Then, the central cell itself is skipped by the `if` check, resulting only on adjacent cells being returned.

Then, to count the asterisks, you just leverage this method:

```
_matrix.NeighborsOf(coordinate).Count(cell => cell.Value == '*');
```

Relying on exceptions to ignore the out-of-bounds coordinates would be considered a bad practice (as it would be an use of the "exception as control flow" anti-pattern) and also fairly poor performance-wise.

The neighbor idea also allows you to parameterize the "size" of the neighbor region, if that's useful to you.

Comment: According to the tests, this `int numOfMines = _matrix.NeighborsOf(coordinate).Count(cell => cell.Value == '*');` returns 0 maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Omar feel free to share your test code so we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: Post edited and tests added, thanks!

Comment: @Omar my bad, fixed the comparisons in the for loops, should work now. Give it a go please.

Comment: Alright, now it works perfectly, thanks! Could you be so kind as to explain to me how those fors work? I'm a bit lost. Thank you again! :) Also, how do you find these kind of patrons?

Comment: @Omar edited with an explanation behind the nested loop idea. It basically iterates over a block of up to 3 x 3 cells: each for loop for one of the dimensions. If this was a 3D matrix, we'd have 3 for loops instead of 2 (for example). The Math operations ensure that the boundaries are respected.

Comment: @Omar as for how one finds the patterns, it may help to try and generalize the problem. For example, what if I wanted to navigate on a 5x5 window of adjacent cells instead of a 3x3 window? This forces you to stop hardcoding values and come up with an approach that generates the "region" for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a method to the `Matrix` class, that returns `true` if both x and y are within their allowed ranges (0 <= x < M, 0 <= y < N) for a given `Coordinate`:

```
public bool IsValid(Coordinate coordinate) =>
         0 <= coordinate.X && coordinate.X < _size.M &&
         0 <= coordinate.Y && coordinate.Y < _size.N;
```

Then you can count only the valid cells:

```
return coordinates.Count(x => _matrix.IsValid(x) && _matrix.At(x).Value == '*');
```

*Additionally, it makes sense to use this method for validation purpose in all other public methods of the `Matrix` class accepting `Coordinate` as an argument.*

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! I was wondering if exists another way to check each coordinate adjacent without hardcoding the coordinate itself. Having 8 coordinates looks awful but for me it feels kinda hard to find the patron there.